# How to distinguish `(() => any) | undefined` from just `() => any` in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, undefined

I have two types: `(() => any) | undefined` and `() => any`. I would like extract the return type of the function but only if the value is definitely not undefined.

I have tried the following:

```
type IsUndefined<T> = T extends (() => any) ? "no" : "yes";
```

But this resolves to `"yes" | "no"` when the type is not undefined. I want to detect the difference between these types without creating a union.

Please see [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgVQHYBMIDM6ouqAXigAoSBKIgPigENURKAfKAVw213wChRJYEiAPatgaTDjwFiFanQbde4aAEkAzuM5SAPABUaxXVAgAPYBAxrSswjXqMoAfigAiVEJdQAXK5AQ1LgDcinzQAEr+rAA2wACCRFDqmpL42vBIyVzoVMGhUBFq0cAAQglJHCnoaYIiYhVZOUA) for an example.

That is the short story, the long story is that I have a struct like the following:

```
type MyStruct = {
    optionalHook?: ((...args: any) => any) | undefined,
    requiredHook: (...args: any) => any,
}
```

I would like to extract the return type of the optional hook, but only when it exists. I would like to extract the return type of the required hook otherwise.

See [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGECcFMEMBdqngCyQc2gO2pAlgMagDO8kArgfAFDwCeADkgLJ0DKZl8APACqjQAHoiwATYqAAUkgHRzYkdMQBcoWFjoBKUAF4AfGo3aAPqHJjoAMzw5RAGlABVAcOzipcmQqWr1W3QZ+BjqgAN7UoJGgAPYM8HjRWLAANgAS0dEA1gD8qrx2EVEwAI7keDCi6VmqjgUAvtTUIE7xyXj0oJbmVAlYndGQArDEeMl0oAQwCDboJPBcEgDu7SjIaBMDMFTIjNAyTWAA6ivR5PBreBIAkgDkoqAosABuSPDRO0xrGNi4hGqK5AAtth4BJAepyCkxv1BtAXpBxqQKNsbKR1AQ9tQulgeokJlNEBxkTx+EIRO5pJ5vCpDP59LSTGYLNZbA5nGS3BJZPJFDS-Np6UFJEiuKBVKwiVw+HZHHptOEoqAYPNIH0RVQANzUBrUAiJUigZaoADycV6KV0+LghM4VEkCqisXiiRSVUyqkkAoMAFYCoqSmUKm6PV7QAAiNDJZLRMP1TRa3X685GlCneCm51JZKWybW6CSu0OyIB8rQSoZd1SUOcaBxhMHUC8dbY3F9SwDFxkWA9LCzVBIZXkVUfaC0XagTDwABK0BVWF4uz4wUKkVJrjEEgltp4NksuFAxocu-3U4M2RXioPnc5TNEVhsZdA58vL-DdGgxDDYtAzTJkG75wznOC6fNEligFODy4KOr6Xjg8Lfr+wj-tsQFDvO45gVeaAwBeirwbg9b0J8M7EOQyTwMcJpmi62YhJOaGqiB0DcMR0BYSmGbmskehamxEEfuRlEnGcXG0ZaDGzuhzGsbsHEiemNFZrxQA) for a more comprehensive example.

Comment: your playground links are broken (likely incomplete)

Comment: Ah thanks for the heads up. It seems my browser wasn't updating the address bar that I copied it from. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why the absence of `optionalHook` doesn't infer `T` to `undefined` in `createStruct` but I've managed to get the desired result by adding default generic parameters:

```
// Create the generic struct
type MyStruct<T extends ((...args: any) => any) | undefined, U extends (...args: any) => any> = {
    optionalHook?: T,
    requiredHook: U,
}

// Utility function for easily creating stucts with the correct type.
// Without this I'd have to type the generic arguments manually for every struct instance.
function createStruct<T extends ((...args: any) => any) | undefined = undefined, U extends (...args: any) => any = (...args: any) => any>(struct: MyStruct<T, U>) {
    return struct;
}

const withOptional = createStruct({
    optionalHook: () => 5,
    requiredHook: () => "hello",
});

const withoutOptional = createStruct({
    requiredHook: () => true,
});


// The function for extracting the return type
type getReturnType<T> =
    T extends MyStruct<infer O, infer R> ?
        O extends (...args: any) => infer OR ?
            OR :
            R extends (...args: any) => infer RR ? RR : never :
        never;


type ResultWithOptional = getReturnType<typeof withOptional>;
type ResultWithoutOptional = getReturnType<typeof withoutOptional>;
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGECcFMEMBdqngCyQc2gO2pAlgMagDO8kArgfAFDwCeADkgLJ0DKZl8APACqjQAHoiwATYqAAUkgHRzYkdMQBcoWFjoBKUAF4AfGo3aAPqHJjoAMzw5RAGlABVAcOzipcmQqWr1W3QZ+BjqgAN7UoJGgAPYM8HjRWLAANgAS0dEA1gD8qrx2EVEwAI7keDCi6VmqjgUAvtTUIE7xyXj0oJbmVAlYndGQArDEeMl0oAQwCDboJPBcEgDu7SjIaBMDMFTIjNAyTWAA6ivR5PBreBIAkgDkoqAosABuSPDRO0xrGNi4hGqK5AAtth4BJAepyCkxv1BtAXpBxqQKNsbKR1AQ9tQulgeokJlNEBxkTx+EIRO5pJ5vCpDP59LSTGYLNZbLomaIrDZoPYnC5yRJZPJFDS-Np6X42YKvMLfEYArS9JIkVxVKwiVw+A5HHptOEoqAYPNIH1lVQANzUBrUAiJUigZaoADycV6KTZkzghM4VEkeqisXiiRSVUyqkkYoMAFYCvqSmUKiGwxHQAAiNDJZLRFP1TQW62284OlCneDOwNJZLugnQdU+v2ROPlbmJqTJzjQHN5g6gXjrbG4vqWAZ8yCwHpYWaoJCG8jGj7QWi7UCYeAAJWgRqwvF2fGChUipNcYgkau9PBsllwoEdDgvV9XBmy+-1175bgFVJlDPld8GjtXoBPi+wHXgByjPiBoAAWS74eEKPjfvSv5QQB2QoaAqg4PCGEQVEWG4F29CfOuxDkMk8DHE6LpBpWIQruum7bkw3BEdA0SWPaKxlq6yR6BarFQdApHkZRxZnNxNFsvRG6zluO6sexnGoCWEkVnxQA)

Explicitly set `optionalHook` to `undefined` also works:

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGECcFMEMBdqngCyQc2gO2pAlgMagDO8kArgfAFDwCeADkgLJ0DKZl8APACqjQAHoiwATYqAAUkgHRzYkdMQBcoWFjoBKUAF4AfGo3aAPqHJjoAMzw5RAGlABVAcOzipcmQqWr1W3QZ+BjqgAN7UoJGgAPYM8HjRWLAANgAS0dEA1gD8qrx2EVEwAI7keDCi6VmqjgUAvtTUIE7xyXj0oJbmVAlYndGQArDEeMl0oAQwCDboJPBcEgDu7SjIaBMDMFTIjNAyTWAA6ivR5PBreBIAkgDkoqAosABuSPDRO0xrGNi4hGqK5AAtth4BJAepyCkxv1BtAXpBxqQKNsbKR1AQ9tQulgeokJlNEBxkTx+EIRO5pJ5vCpDP59LSTGYLNZbA5nGS3BJZPJFDS-Np6UFJEiuKpWESuHw2XptOEoqAYPNIH0RVQANzUBrUAiJUigZaoADycV6KV0+LghM4VEkcqisXiiRSVUyqkkAoMAFYCvKSmUKi63R7QAAiNDJZLREP1TQa7W684GlCneDGx1JZLmyaW6ASm12yIO01pDKupmiKw2aD2QqRP3lauBqTBzjQGNxg6gXjrbG4vqWAYuMiwHpYWaoJCK8jKj7QWi7UCYeAAJWgSqwvF2fGCta7Q85oHF1p4NksuFAhocp-Py4M2V38sN+7EXKpvN8RgCoGvg0Ny9A97ykBUR-qAygPsBoD-hyL4eDyPgMl+P5Qf+2QoWBoA4PCYEQZEWG4B29CfKuxDkMk8DHEaJpOpmIRLqu66bkw3BEdA0SWPqKxpsWegaqxUHQKR5GUcmZzcTR5r0Wu04blurHsZxqApuJGa8UAA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom util like this:

```
export const isSet = <T>(value: T | null | undefined): value is T => {
  return value != null;
};
```

And then use it:

```
let something; // (() => any) | undefined
if (isSet(something)) {
  doSomething(something); // () => any
}
```

And if you need the opposite (i.e. check that a type is undefined), then you don't even need a custom util, you can use lodash — either [isUndefined](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isUndefined) or [isNil](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isNil) (= is undefined or null).

Comment: Ah sorry I should have mentioned, I'm looking for a way to do this in a `.d.ts` file. So I can't make use of any kind of runnable script. It is types only so I'll need to do the check at compile time rather than runtime.